# Display callstack without method names

Tags: windbg, callstack

In WinDbg, I can get the callstack using the `k` command. For DLLs without symbols, it displays an incorrect method name and a large offset, e.g.

```
0018f9f0 77641148 syncSourceDll_x86!CreateTimerSyncBridge+0xc76a
```

Since I don't have symbols, I have to give this information to the developer of the DLL. I don't know who will work on the bug and how much debugging knowledge he has. I want to avoid that the developer thinks the problem is in the CreateTimerSyncBridge() method.

**Is there a way to get the callstack without method names, just with offsets?**

At the moment I'm using the following workaround:

```
0:000> ? syncSourceDll_x86!CreateTimerSyncBridge+0xc76a
Evaluate expression: 1834469050 = 6d57c6ba
0:000> ? syncSourceDll_x86
Evaluate expression: 1834287104 = 6d550000
0:000> ? 6d57c6ba-6d550000
Evaluate expression: 181946 = 0002c6ba
```

So I can modify the callstack manually to

```
0018f9f0 77641148 syncSourceDll_x86!+0x2c6ba
```

But that's really hard to do for a lot of frames in a lot of threads.

Comment: You could just set the symbol options to be very strict so it shouldn't generate the incorrect symbol match `.symopt +0x400` see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558827(v=vs.85).aspx#symopt_exact_symbols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify that the symbols must match exactly using a stricter evaluation, either by starting windbg with command line parameter `-ses` or issuing the command:

`.symopt +0x400`

The default is false for the debugger, if you wish to reset this then just remove the option:

`.symopt -0x400`

See the msdn docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558827(v=vs.85).aspx#symopt_exact_symbols