# How to find the fault offset from faluting IP

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windbg, crash-dumps

I have the following information regarding a application crash, I want to know the fault offset, because given a fault offset, we have a tool which can determine the line of source which caused the crash.
The faulting module is a COM dll

```
Exception code: C00000005 (Access Violation)

 - FALUTING_IP:MyModule!DllUnregisterServer+0x00010f0d 
 - ExceptionAddress:05d0f2ed 
 - FOLLOWUP_IP:MyModule!DllUnregisterServer+10f0d 
 - MyModule is loaded at start:05cf0000   end:05d4c000
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up symbols in WinDbg?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg)

Comment: Faulting offset from what? from a function ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display callstack without method names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451803/display-callstack-without-method-names)

Comment: @Nuno_147 , the IP is pointing to 05d0f2ed and we know the dll memory start and end range, can we determine the fault offset , which may point to the location in the dll source code, where the crash occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the relative offset to the beginning of the DLL by

```
?  MyModule!DllUnregisterServer+0x00010f0d  - MyModule
// DLL Offset+ Method offset   +byte offset - DLL offset
```

The result will be given in decimal and hex:

```
Evaluate expression: 446065 = 0006ce71
```

Comment: could you please elaborate , how did you arrive at 0006ce71

Comment: @user2101801: that's just an example. I didn't have a DLL called MyModule, so I took something else